# Bilinear Forms: An Initial Condition Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B$ be a bilinear form on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose that for any nonzero vector $v \in V$ there exists a $w \in V$ such that $B(v, w)\neq 0$. Prove that for any linear functional $f \in V^*$ there exists a $v \in V$ such that $f(w) = B(v, w)$ for all $w \in V$.

Some of these proofs seem really simple, but I'm making this overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy proof of this fact:

Look at the map $\varphi:V\rightarrow V^\star, v\mapsto (w\mapsto B(v,w))$.

$\varphi$ is a linear map and according to your assumption it is also injective : 
$\ker(\varphi)=\{v\in V, \varphi(v)=0 \}=\{v\in V, \forall w\in V, B(v,w)=0\}=\{0\}$.

Since $V$ and $V^\star$ have the same dimension, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism and we are done.

Comment: Oh, wow, I like your star. How do typeset it? $\star$

Comment: Oh, OK it is just \star. How intuitive.

Comment: What is $\varphi$ here to be clear? Could you explain also what the map means?

Comment: This is the map that takes a vector $v\in V$ and gives us the linear form $\varphi(v): w\mapsto B(v,w)$. To be sure you well understand $\varphi$, check that it is linear for example.